# sockeio Java client namespace connection ack failed

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io

Socket io server has a namespace for customers

```
let customers = io.of('/customers');

customers.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log("connected");

    socket.on('disconnect', function (){
             console.log('disconnected from server');
    });

});

io.on('connection', async function (socket) {
    console.log("connected");
  socket.disconnect();

  socket.on('disconnect', function (){
                 console.log('disconnected from server');
        });

  });
```

if anyone connected to root namespace I will disconnect.

My android client

```
    Manager manager = new Manager(new URI("http://localhost:3000"));
    Socket  socket = manager.socket("/customers", options);

    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i("CustomerService", "EVENT_CONNECT");
                }
       }
```

**EVENT_CONNECT call back is not triggering for the above server code.**
What could be an issue ?

Comment: don't try async await untill you don't have understanding of async programming . also check offical repo https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat

Comment: @shivshankar Thanks. Is there any issue with asyn programming with socket io. I know it returns a promise. or can use callback. all same right ?